# Why am I only getting the result of Case 1 in this VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, case

When I run my lines of code I get 5 "meow" MsgBoxes instead of "meow" and "woof"

```
Dim animal As Range
Set animal = shB.Range("M3:M8")

For Each Cell In animal

    Select Case Cell
        Case Is = cat
            MsgBox "meow"
        Case Is = dog
            MsgBox "woof"
    End Select

Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `Case Is = cat`... `Case "cat"`? You need to add `Option Explicit` to your module and declare all your variables.

Comment: Thanks @bigben I have tried Case "cat" that did not change anything as well as defining cat and dog as Strings

Comment: You should also be explicit: `Select Case Cell.Value`...

Comment: It well return `meow` when checking an empty cell. In your code, `cat` is an empty variant. So when a `Cell` becomes and empty cell, the first `Case` will trigger.  Otherwise, no `Case` will trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, `Option Explicit` will help you write your code accurately and allow you to quickly identify gaps/errors. You should declare all your variables then assign your variables appropriately within your code.

In your example, you have ***not*** declared what is shB for example.

With Select Case statements, you can use `Case Is`, although I ***don't*** think you can use `Case Is =`

Try this; I tested and it works for me -

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectCase_Example()
 Dim wshB As Worksheet
 Dim rAnimal As Range
 Dim rCell As Range

    Set wshB = ActiveSheet
    Set rAnimal = wshB.Range("M3:M8")

    For Each rCell In rAnimal
        Select Case rCell
            Case "cat"
                MsgBox "Meow!"
            Case "dog"
                MsgBox "woof!"
        End Select
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: It weird when I tested this it goes case 1, 2, 1, 2 regardless of the actual order.

Comment: You can use `Case Is =`, but it's clunky here and probably should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for correction on `Case Is =` @BigBen I'll note that for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sounds()

  Dim animal As Range
  Dim cell   As Range

  Set animal = ActiveSheet.Range("M3:M8")

  For Each cell In animal

    Select Case cell
        Case Is = "cat"
            MsgBox "meow"
        Case Is = "dog"
            MsgBox "woof"
    End Select

  Next cell

End Sub
```